# Python use string variable as index/key for nested list/dict

Tags: python-3.x

```
data = {'virtualInterfaces': [{"interfaceName": "abc", "interfaceState": "online"}, {"interfaceName": "axc", "interfaceState": "online"}, {"interfaceName": "xpto", "interfaceState": "offline"}]}

foo = "['virtualInterfaces'][2]['interfaceState']"
```

I need to use the var "foo" to get a specific value from `data`

e.g

```
data[foo] #should return "offline"
```

I tried to use eval

`value = eval(data + foo)`

But didn´t work.
Foo can have any number of nested list/dict

Comment: why not just using `foo` as a tuple of nested keys?

Comment: you should carefully consider whether this  design is necessary. It would be easier just to take a sequence of indices instead of dynamicalyl evaluating strings

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am using DeepDiff in 2 json files, DeepDiff returns a string with the position (index) of the difference, based on this position I need to pick another piece of information in the same json. So, in this specific situation, the use of eval is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` contains the literal indexing string, whereas `data` is not a string, but the dictionary object. So you have to put `data` in quotes to use `eval`:

```py
value = eval('data' + foo)
```